# reg save -> ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Tags: batch, windows-registry

I would like to save/backup all registry entries that accumulate over a while in a certain part of the registry.

So far I have tried in the command window which I opened with admin rights:

```
reg save HKCU\Software\ACD Systems\EditLib\Version 1.0\Develop\Presets\Global D:\AFElcDev\NeuEinrichten\Batches\BatchGeneratedBackups\ACDSee\REGISTRY_ACDSeeDevelopPresets.log /y
```

aAnd not being sure if it can read the registry path with spaces also:

```
reg save "HKCU\Software\ACD Systems\EditLib\Version 1.0\Develop\Presets\Global" D:\AFElcDev\NeuEinrichten\Batches\BatchGeneratedBackups\ACDSee\REGISTRY_ACDSeeDevelopPresets.log /y
```

Both gave the same result:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
```

How should I do this?
Windows 10 Pro, 64-Bit

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you export the key, using the registry editor, then modify that file?

Comment: Use double quotes to escape space(s) in registry key as follows: `reg save "HKCU\Software\ACD Systems\EditLib\Version 1.0\Develop\Presets\Global" …`

Comment: @HJStern - My suggestion was an attempt to hint that you need to better understand how to export the key using proper syntax.  My suggestion would have put you on that path.  Instead of submitting a comment for every command that doesn't work you should **edit** your question.  However, we don't need to know, every variation of what doesn't work.

Comment: @JosefZ: I am sorry but in my first version of the post I forgot to add the quotes in my second example (I edited my post and added the quotes). But it does now work with the quotes either. I also made sure, that the path in the command is exactly the same as in the registry (by copying it from the registry - just as you suggested). But all to no avail, I still get the same error.

Comment: @Ramhound I also exported keys directly from the registry but it did not really help. Yes, exporting the key puts the path into square brackets but if I use only square brackets I still run into ERROR: Invalid key name. and writes out HKCU as HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Putting quotes at the beginning and the end of the filename, inside of the bracket or outside of the still ERROR: Invalid key name

Comment: I did not solve the problem yet but posted my question also to the microsoft community and followed a suggestion to use reg export instead of reg save. This interestingly enough works completely as expected even though it does not preserve  key ownership and ACLs.